# .float-right & .float-left doesn't work inside a .row in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, css-float

In bootstrap 4 float not working inside in row.

i need right div in left and left div in right but in responsive view i need right div first and then left div.

```
    <div class="row">
     <div class="right col-md-4">
         float Right
     </div>
    <div class="left col-md-8">
       float left
    </div>
  </div>
```

But now float not working

Comment: I think the class names are *float-left* and *float-right*. Check it out [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/)

Comment: No its not working

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use both it means float-left and float-right, first you should wrap these divs in clearfix class.

```
<div class="clearfix">
 <span class="float-left">Float left</span>
 <span class="float-right">Float right</span>
</div>
```